# Tablet stream (snappy)

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Laravel 6.0+
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

here is my problem. I would like that on tablet I can print the pdf directly or then be able to stream the pdf as on the pc.

because currently on tablet I have to download the pdf, open the pdf, and print the pdf. 
I would like to simplify all that.

```
public function pdf()
{
    $order = Order::first()
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin/pdf.order', compact('order'));

    return $pdf->stream('Pdf_'. $order->num_order .'_'. $order->customer->name);

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's a browser's viewer issue. Can you provide your admin/pdf.order view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem I am going through an html basic view with a button in javascript which asks to print and which directly starts printing!